# Proguard Removing Overridden resource id in android library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-resources, android-proguard

I have a library with an LegendActivity using layout legend.xml which references a view with id "icons".  Now, in my app, I subclass this activity with "AppLegendActivity" and use the app's overriding legend.xml which *does not* include any view with id "icons".

Library

```
public class LegendActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        setContentView(R.layout.legend);

        View icons_view = findViewById(R.id.icons);
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/icons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

App

```
public class AppLegendActivity extends LegendActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(Bundle b);

        View app_icons_view = findViewById(R.id.app_icons);
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/app_icons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This is an over-simplification of my actual code, but this is the crux of the problem.  When I run pro-guard I get the following error:

```
Warning: com.example.activity.LegendActivity: can't find referenced field 'int icons' in program class com.example.R$id
```

If I add the "-dontwarn" flag in proguard, I can get the app to compile, but as soon as the AppLegendActivity calls super.onCreate, the reference to R.id.icons gets called and the app crashes with:

```
ava.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.example.r.icons
```

App's build.grade referencing proguard section:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
            // Proguard 
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

My proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn com.example.**
```

Can this code be re-factored to avoid this crash?  Yes.  Can I simply rename a few resources files and get this conflict to go away?  Sure.  But in the actual project, this much more complicated and I don't know the full extend of the implications of such a refactor.  Is there a way to get the library's R file to not remove/obfuscate IDs that are no longer visible after the app's overriding of resources?

Answer (score 0):

In `AppLegendActivity` class you override `LegendActivity` you need change         `setContentView(R.layout.....);` or remove `super.onCreate(Bundle b);`

Comment: Yes, this is the refactoring that I mentioned I did not want to do.  The actual code itself is much more complicated and, as this is a library, used by multiple apps; this can have unintended consequences I don't even know yet.  I'm looking for a way, given the current code, that works without proguard, to make it work with proguard plus a few configurations.